# Запрос MySQL на удаление одинаковых строк

Tags: запрос, mysql

Ситуация следующая, есть в таблице записи:

```
id  user_id  field_id  value
1     16        6        test
2     16        6        test2
3     16        7        test3
4     16        6        test
```

Необходимо одним запросом удалить из данной таблицы строки, где есть хоть 1 копия "user_id+field_id".

Т.е. не может существовать две и более строки у которых поля "user_id" и "field_id" совпадают.

В результате должны удалиться строки с id 1 и 4.

За раннее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: > За раннее

**Заранее**

MySQL, если я правильно помню, запрещает изменения таблицы на основе данных, полученных из той же таблицы. Это вполне решается через двойной селект, если не проще, но, возможно, стоит все-таки разделить на два запроса (если, конечно, такая возможность существует).

Comment: Возможно. Такая возможность существует. Но вроде как выкрутился.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо выкрутить через `delete inner join`. Примерно так:

```
delete t1.* from table as t1 inner join 
   (
       select concat(cast(field_id as varchar), value) as s
   ) t2 
   on concat(cast(t1.field_id as varchar), t1.value)=t2.s
```

Comment: Если честно это сложновато для моего понимания. Думаю после 10ти часов раздумья я нашел верный запрос.
SELECT id FROM table as f WHERE EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM table as ff WHERE f.user_id = ff.user_id AND f.field_id = ff.field_id AND f.id < ff.id)